# transition of polygon opacity in google maps v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to see the transition of colors from zero opacity to 1. The idea is that you can see the transition of color, but not how to do it, this is the code that I have:

```
var geocoder;
var shape = [];
var map;
// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
var coordinates = [
    [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262)],

    [
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.990236, -89.296875),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.163403, -86.835938),
    new google.maps.LatLng(42.163403, -76.113281)]
];

function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.394070, -78.515056),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

}

function update(color) {
    for (var i in coordinates) {
        var options = ({
            path: coordinates[i],
            strokeColor: 'black',
            strokeOpacity: 0.3,

            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: color,
            fillOpacity: 0.9,
            zIndex: 1,
            map: map
        });
        if ( !! shape[i] && !! shape[i].setMap) {
            shape[i].setMap(null);
        }
        shape[i] = new google.maps.Polygon(options);
    }
}
var i = 0

    function reload() {
        i = i + 1;
        var color = "#FFFFFF";

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            color = "#0000FF";
        }
        update(color);
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

I have an idea to do with this piece of code of code but not if it works, and it runs very fast.

```
var opa = 0;
while (opa <= 1) {
   shape[i].setMap(null);
   shape[i].fillOpacity = opa;
   shape[i].setMap(map);
   opa = opa + 0.1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qqgmhcmo/

Comment: related/duplicate question: [transition fillcolor google maps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30947449/transition-fillcolor-google-maps)

Comment: is different....in this i speak of opacity..

Comment: @yeisonvelez11 so why is this question titled 'transition of color fill'?  The two questions are so similar; if you can find an approach to transition the gradient, you can probably find one to transition the opacity.  Just wait for an answer to your first question I think.

Answer (score 0):

add a `window.setTimeout();` around the code inside your while loop.  e.g.

```
var opa=0;
while(opa<=1){
   window.setTimeout(function() {
      shape[i].setMap(null);
      shape[i].fillOpacity=opa;
      shape[i].setMap(map);
      opa=opa+0.1;
   }, 500);
}
```

Comment: do not get the desired effect with timeout function

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what _"the desired effect"_ is?

Comment: I hope you can understand, I do not speak English. the "desired effect" consists of a small color transition from one color to another, as in google maps is not the way to generate a color gradient, my idea is to make the opacity effect, that when a color change another, opacity decreases to zero and increases with other color.